# Need help for java to randomly decide between male or female

Tags: java

I am new to coding, and I am currently modding a code. Here is pat of the original.

```
 if ((world[row][col] == ORGANISM) && (check == 2))
            worldCopy[row][col] = ORGANISM;
```

The original code would basically spawn a offspring (a.k.a a *) in a certain location on a grid. However, now I am modding for the offspring to be randomly male or female. How should I write a new piece of subcode so that it would randomly pick for ORGANISM to be male or female? I don't need specifics, just want some help because I am stuck.

Comment: First, your posted code doesn't seem to be important for your question.  Second: have you searched for *Java random value* or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Random class. It provides random generation of ints, and in your case, booleans. I don't know what data type organism is, but something like this should help:

```
if(new Random().nextBoolean()) {
    //Male
} else {
    //Female
}
```

Inside those statements, set the type of organism (I'm guessing that's an enum variable)

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() method can be used which returns a decimal number between 0.0 to 1.0. A check can be done to see if the value is > or < 0.5 and decide based on that.

```
String gender;
if(Math.random() > 0.5) gender  = "MALE";
else gender = "FEMALE";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. :)